# How to limit webpack DllReferencePlugin to certain chunks?

Tags: webpack

Is there a way I can limit a webpack.DllReferencePlugin to only be included by certain chunks? For example, if I have the following entry, plugins:

```
entry: {
  application: ['./app/application.js', './assets/less/application.less'],
  marketing: ['./app/marketing.js', './assets/less/marketing.less'],
  shared: ['./app/shared.js', './assets/less/shared.less']
}

plugins: [
  new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/shared-vendor-manifest.json')
  }),
  new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
    manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/application-vendor-manifest.json'),
    chunks: ['application']
  })
]
```

I would like to allow only the "application" chunk to see "application-vendor-manifest.json"